# How does the Ambitious Schemer racial trait for Drow work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, class, races, racial-traits

I'm confused here. It is written "You may choose either Bluff or Diplomacy as a class skill, and gain a +2 bonus on such skill checks." So, how it works with regular class skills?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RAW, it means that you add Bluff or Diplomacy -your choice- to your class skills (check the corresponding box), and gain a +2 (to write in the Misc. Mod column of your sheet) to the skill. If both are already class skills, well, that's something the trait won't bring you. You still get the +2 though. Since it is considered a class skill, you also get the corresponding +3 bonus if you put ranks in it.

Comment: And when it is a class skill (for that race trait only) it means, i will get next +3 bonus when i put here rank? Even if it is not regular class skill from a class?

Comment: Yes. You get the +3 bonus from the first rank you put in a skill that is considered a class skill at that time. This also works when multiclassing. I'll edit to reflect that.